# Python - Pygame - circular movement

Tags: python, pygame

I´ve the following code:

```
import pygame, sys, math

run = True
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)
angle = 0
size = width, height = 800, 800
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen.fill(white)

while run:
    msElapsed = clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    screen.fill(white)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (int(math.cos(angle) * 100), int(math.sin(angle) * 100)), 10)

    pygame.display.flip()
    angle += 0.05

pygame.quit()
```

this creates me a circle, which circles around the coordination (0, 0). 
i want to move the center from (0, 0) to (100, 100).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add 100 to the x and y coordinates to adjust the center position:

```
x = int(math.cos(angle) * 100) + 100
y = int(math.sin(angle) * 100) + 100
pygame.draw.circle(screen, black, (x, y), 10)
```